Pigeonhole Principle Application: Counting number of triangles
There are 13 points randomly placed on the periphery of a circle. Now construct a graph, where the vertices are the given 13 points and two points are
connected by an edge iff the angle formed by extending two points to the
center is less than 90◦
. Show that there is at least 7 triangles in that graph.
What I tried:
I divided the circle into four equal quadrants, subtending 90◦ each at center. Then one quadrant has atleast $⌈13/4⌉=4$ points in it.
Therefore minimum ${4\choose 3}$ triangles exist in this. I'm unable to prove for 7. Please help

If there are $n$ points in any quadrant, there are ${n\choose 3}$ triangles formed in that quadrant.  There must be one quadrant with at least 4 points creating 4 triangles in that quadrant.  This puts 3 points in each of the other 3 quadrants, creating 3 more triangles.  Any other distribution will create more triangles.

thank you so much! i spent way too much time banging my head on this problem.
